# Kafka connect not working for file streaming

Tags: streaming, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have been using Kafka connect for the confluent platform using the following guide

[Kafka connect quickstart](http://docs.confluent.io/2.0.0/connect/intro.html)

But it doesn't update the sink file anymore, any changes in the source file are not written in the kafka topic.

I have already deleted all tmp files but no change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Start up a new file source connector with a new location for storing the offsets. This connector is meant as a demo and really doesn't handle anything except a simple file that only gets append updates. Note, you shouldn't be doing anything with this connector other than a simple demo. Have a look at the connector hub if you need something for production.

Comment: If the intent of the "demo" is to demonstrate that connectors can fail irrevocably without explanation or error... mission accomplished.  Neither deleting and re-adding the connector, nor deleting and recreating the topic, nor restarting all connect nodes will get this simple connector working again. Yet, simply changing the name to get a fresh connector works, until that too breaks.  There are no errors or clues in logs.  I think it's fair to say the file sink connector is unsuitable even for a demo... ESPECIALLY for a demo. It's demonstrating how brittle the system is.

Comment: I mean, it's been over 4 years. You should really consider trying one is the myriad of other demos. The doc linked to the original post is even marked to point you to the new stuff. Also know that I want you to find happiness in life and send you a virtual hug.  https://docs.confluent.io/home/tutorials.html

Answer (score 1):

The **FileStreamSource/Sink** does not work after it worked fine and you've already restarted the zookeeper, kafka server and the connector but still it does not work then the problem is with the **CONNECT.OFFSETS** file in the kafka directory.
You should delete it and create a new empty one.

Comment: yeah, zookeeper needs to restarted

Answer (score 0):

To OP, I have had this like 5 mins ago but when I restarted the connector it's fine, both test.sink.txt and the consumer are getting new line added. So in a nutshell, just restart your connector.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem before. But correcting the path of the input and output files in the properties files as below worked for me. And it streamed from input file(`test.txt`) to output file(`test.sink.txt`).

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=/home/mypath/kafka/test.txt
topic=connect-test

name=local-file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=/home/mypath/kafka/test.sink.txt
topics=connect-test
```